# Anti blot system on spoj

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I stuck at a problem [Anti Blot](https://www.spoj.com/problems/ABSYS/)

I executed my program on all the test cases ,I am getting correct answer.

But still I am getting as "wrong answer" on spoj

What I have tried:

Breaking stream into strings storing them into vectors ,so we can say that 
our vector will have 5 strings (numstring,+,numstring,=,numstring) and then we will inspect each string whenever we found `m` in the string ,we get to know that 
string at this position is variable that need to be calculated with the help of other digits strings

And we are also certain about that string with digits can only be at `0,2,4` indices in the vectors other two indices will have `+ and =`

Test cases:

Input:

> 3
>
> 23 + 47 = machula
>
> 3247 + 5machula2 = 3749
>
> machula13 + 75425 = 77038

Output:

> 23 + 47 = 70
>
> 3247 + 502 = 3749
>
> 1613 + 75425 = 77038

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int t;
    (cin >> t).get();
    while (t--) {
        string str;

        getline(cin, str);
        stringstream split(str);
        string each;
        vector <string> tokens;
        while (getline(split, each, ' ')) {
            ///scan each part of stream;
            tokens.push_back(each);

        }
        int ind = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
            string temp;
            temp = tokens[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.length(); j++) {
                if (temp[j] == 'm') {
                    ind = i;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (ind != -1)
                break;
        }
        int i1, i2;
        string str1;
        if (ind == 0) {
            i1 = stoi(tokens[2]);
            i2 = stoi(tokens[4]);
            int result = i2 - i1;
            cout << result << " + " << i1 << " = " << i2 << "\n";
            //break;
        }
        else if (ind == 2) {
            i1 = stoi(tokens[0]);
            i2 = stoi(tokens[4]);
            int result;
            result = i2 - i1;
            cout << i1 << " + " << result << " = " << i2 << "\n";
            //break;
        }
        else if (ind == 4) {
            i1 = stoi(tokens[0]);
            i2 = stoi(tokens[2]);
            int result = i1 + i2;
            cout << i1 << " + " << i2 << " = " << result << "\n";
            //break;
        }
        tokens.clear();
        str.erase();
    }


}
```

Comment: Impossible to tell which test cases are applied to your code by SPOJ, since these aren't disclosed. If you think your program works properly with all your test cases you tried, you may ask for improvement at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions). Here you are required to show a [mcve] along with the problem you observe exactly. Otherwise your question is _off-topic_.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is annoying, your solution has no logical errors, but you should read the problem description more carefully. It says:

> Each test case is preceded by a blank line.

So the input is:

```
3

23 + 47 = machula

3247 + 5machula2 = 3749

machula13 + 75425 = 77038
```

Pay attention to the blank lines between the rows.
Just fix your code to:

```
// Blablabla before getline
getline(cin, str);
getline(cin, str);
stringstream split(str);
// The rest of your code
```

and that should do the trick.

Comment: can you please explain the logic of using an extra getline here?

Comment: It is just a matter of reading the input correctly, which the original code does not. There is a blank line before each input line. It is simply the way it is. That is how the authors of the problem decided to format the input. So what the extra getline does is simply skipping the blank line and going to the next actual input. Apart from that this solution works.

Comment: Using another `getline()` call just to eat the line break is excessive. You can use `cin.ignore()` instead.